# Not able to open file directories from gmrun

Tags: gnome, gmrun

I have been using gmrun to launch programs like run dialog in the windows.

One thing annoying me is i am not able launch file directories from gmrun.

I am entering the path in gmrun dialog box and enter OK..Nothing happens after that..[image]

It would be very nice if we can do that..

Is there anything i am missing here?

I am using pure Ubuntu 10.04LTS with gnome desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should enter it as:

> nautilus /home/ram/Downloads

Since not all of these application launchers have the ability to launch directories by launching the file manager.

Comment: I was thinking to add `nautilus` but i assumed it requires `sudo` also at the begining..Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @javanoob: sudo is only required to open something as root, and in such a case you would want to use `gksu` and not `sudo` :)